# JSch connection issue: JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail – Even with JCE installed

Tags: java, session, ssh, connection, jsch

I am trying to connect to a server using JSch but it gives issues with connection. I am able to connect to the server using PuTTY but not using Java code.

I am using jdk1.8.0_171

Here is the code snippet

```
session = jsch.getSession(username, server, SSH_PORT);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setTimeout(timeout);
session.connect(timeout);
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:590)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
```

Below are the JSch logs:

```
INFO: Connecting to <servername> port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
INFO: kex: server: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
INFO: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
INFO: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: Disconnecting from <servername> port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
```

Here is the pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

I also tried using JSch 0.1.55, still the same issue.

I have checked the [JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263630/jschexception-algorithm-negotiation-fail). But as you can see in the log, all ciphers are available.

It would be preferable if no changes are done on the server side.

How do I solve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try https://github.com/mwiede/jsch it supports more algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> INFO: kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512

JSch (as of 0.1.55) does not support any of those KEX algorithms.

You will have to have the server support some of the algorithms that JSch supports or switch to another SSH client library. JSch is not maintained anymore. But there's a clone of it, that supports modern algorithms: https://github.com/mwiede/jsch.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).*

*For the correct (and secure) approach, see:

[How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848)*

Comment: Switching to some other SSH client. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are facing this issue, change your pom from:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mwiede/jsch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.72</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the repository: https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

Comment: Actually with different server I had to downgrade version of com.github.mwiede jsch library from 0.2.1 (used by Camel for sftp) to 0.1.72