# Spring Cloud Config Server 'Algorithm negotiation fail' Problem

Tags: jsch, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm trying to set up Spring Cloud Config that connects to remote Git repository using SSH but keep getting error 'Algorithm negotiation fail'. [Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796891/jsch-connection-issue-jschexception-algorithm-negotiation-fail-even-with-jce) suggested that I change the SSH client because Jsch 0.1.55 does not support certain kex algorithms, but JSch is used by JGit which in turns by Spring Cloud Config so it's not really an option, is it?.

I can connect to the repository just fine using HTTPS, is it really the only option for now?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

James

Comment: have you already tried to exchange old jsch jar with com.github.mwiede.jsch jar? There was an issue reported in https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/issues/85 but it has been fixed with jgit 5.13

Comment: Tried your suggestion using v0.2.2 & failed w/ NPE:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.setConfig(JSch.java:670)

Comment: Which jgit version is on your classpath?

Comment: It's 5.12.0.202106070339-r. Tried to use v6.x but failed w/ error Parameter 0 of method defaultEnvironmentRepository in org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.DefaultRepositoryConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepositoryFactory' that could not be found.

Comment: you need jgit at least 5.13 to get rid of the NPE, as mentioned above

Comment: Tried 5.13.1.202206130422-r still failed w/ NPE.

Comment: I guess you have a caching problem or so. I setup a blank project like I posted in the answer and the test is green.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.2` and `jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r` like in the following setup:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependencies>
        <!-- Git -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.1.202206130422-r</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.1.202206130422-r</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**junit Test**

```java
@Test
void gitClone() {
    CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository()
            .setURI("git@github.com:mwiede/jsch.git")
            .setDirectory(new File("target/junit/clone-test"));

    assertDoesNotThrow(cloneCommand::call).close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your test snippet. It runs fine, but it also runs fine with the problematic version of JGit & JSch.

Comment: Yes, it works with problematic version of JGit & JSch as long as the kex algorithm negotiation finds a match. when ssh-rsa and ssh-dss were removed on server side, it won't work.