When I try to connect to an SFTP server using Mirth, an 'algorithm negotiation failed' error appears
I'm using Mirth version 3.5.2 to connect to an SFTP server. The connection only requires a username and a password. However, when I press the "Test Write" button to test the connection, the error "Algorithm negotiation failed" appears.
I would greatly appreciate your help with this issue.
I was expecting a successful connection to the SFTP server, as the username and password are correct. I am using password authentication in the SFTP settings.

I do not know Mirth, but seeing it is implemented in Java and the error message, I guess it uses JSch under the hood for SFTP implementation. "Algorithm negotiation failed" is JSch error message – it has nothing to do with your credentials. Recently, the original JSch has problems with modern servers. There are in-place replacement alternatives, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/62796891/850848
