# Unable to connect to SFTP in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, sftp

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server that I created using Docker. When I connect via FileZilla everything is fine.

[FileZilla connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Ytm.png)

logs:
logs after connecting from FileZilla:

```
 Accepted password for user from 000.00.0.0 port 54200 ssh2
```

However, when I try to use the JSch library through Jave, it gives me the error
`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail`
].
It looks like it might be an ssh key problem, but I've disabled JSch.setConfig authorship ("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
I tried to use other libraries, still the same.
Each tip will be valuable :)

```
    @SneakyThrows
    public void upload() {
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = setupJsch();
        channelSftp.connect();
        String localFile = "/home/user/sftp/src/main/resources/text.txt";
        String remoteDir = "/upload/";
        channelSftp.put(localFile, remoteDir + "testFile.txt");
        channelSftp.exit();

    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public ChannelSftp setupJsch() {
        JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(user, host, 2222);
        jschSession.setPassword(password);
        jschSession.connect();
        return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
    }

}
```

logs after trying to connect to server from Java"
`Unable to negotiate with 000.00.0.0 port 54212: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 [preauth]`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl 
What do you mean by two different errors? I can't connect via Java to sftp server.

Comment: See [JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6263630/850848) and for the original problem see [How to resolve Java UnknownHostKey, while using JSch SFTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852906/850848) (`StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is a security flaw). Basically, both these have been asked zillion times already. – If neither helps, post [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848). +